# Add jquery inside c# views MVC 2

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I want to check if there is a value inside a td tag and I want to write something if there isn't, how can I do it from the View directly from MVC View (VS 2010, MVC 2, and no, I can't use newer versions of VS)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <% while(%>&("#<%Response.Write(((k*10)+u+newContador).ToString()); %>").val()<% != "") { %> 

        $("#<%Response.Write(((k*10)+u+newContador).ToString());%>").append("<%Response.Write(newContador.ToString());%>");
        <% newContador++; %>

    <% } %>
</script>
```

Im trying to do something like `CS1525: Invalid expression term '!='`
and others. If someone know if it's possible let me know, if it's not, can I do it in any other way?

Other error that I get is:

```
Line 784:            #line hidden
Line 785:            this.@__PageInspector_EndRenderTracing(new object[] {
Line 786:                        @__w});
Line 787:            this.@__PageInspector_BeginRenderTracing(new object[]  {
Line 788:                        @__w,
```

Comment: "I want to check if there is a value inside a and I..." You accidentally a word.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Can you post what you'd expect the generated JavaScript to look like (after C# has been executed)?

Comment: I would expect the javascript to generate: $("#someNumber").append("someValue"); an example can be $("#23").append("12");

Comment: Okay, then your current code seems to be trying to call a C# while() loop on a JavaScript evaluation. This is not possible. Is the while() meant to be inside C# script tags?

Comment: This it's meant to be inside, but why isn't it inside? I put it inside <% tag

Comment: Did you mean to do something like `while($("#<% Response.Write(SomeCSharpValue); %>").val() != "") { }` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, i want to get a csharp value and if the td value has nothing then put someCSharp value inside

Comment: Okay, so you won't be able to run custom C# code based on the evaluation of a JavaScript field, but you could emit the fallback value into a JS variable, and use it if the JavaScript .val() call returns empty.

Comment: Ohh perfect!! Thanks alot! :) Do you know how to put the answer as correct? Since I'm new with this I don't know what to do once someone has helped me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not valid to mix a JavaScript logic evaluation with a C# while loop as the C# runs on the server before the client ever executes JavaScript. What you can do is emit the value that JavaScript should use from C# into a JavaScript variable, and then when the .val() test is executed in JavaScript, read that JavaScript variable.